# JPanel not calling paintComponent in java

Tags: java, swing

I have worked on this for hours upon hours and it doesn't work.
I want to have a pixel appear on the screen, but the paint component doesn't work I don't understand why.
The `setupFrame` method is called from the main method.

```
public static void setupFrame()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("graphicsTest");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 1080, 1080/2);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(1080, 1080/2);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.repaint();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overloading the `paintComponent()` in the class you've created (let's call it `MyPanel`) but you're creating an instance of another class:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

So there's no instance of MyPanel here and the method is not called. You need to use the class where you've overloaded the paintComponent method:

```
MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
```

Or (this should be equivalent):

```
JPanel panel = new MyPanel();
```